# Linq iterate a control collection

Tags: vb.net, linq

```
   Private Function GetWebDataGridOKButtonId() As String
        Dim ctls As ControlCollection = _
        WebDataGrid1.Controls(0).Controls(0).Controls

        Dim btn As Button
        Dim qry = From item As Control In ctls _
            Where item.ID = "ButtonOK" _
        Select item

        btn = qry.ToList()

        Return btn.ClientID

    End Function
```

This is not working for me. I am trying to iterate a control collection and return one control ID. I am kind of a newbie to linq.

Thanks,
~ck

Comment: Does it throw any error? If so, could you post that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you think there's only one button with a button ID of "ButtonOK"?  If so, then replace

```
btn = qry.ToList()
```

with

```
btn = qry.Single()
```

and things will be how you expect.  Right now, you're getting back a `List<T>` of one item, not a reference to a single item.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than use LINQ, you should just use the [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) method on ButtonOK's parent.